# Select getting an object instead of a string value

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm trying to make to a form in order to add a `user` in the database but in this form i wanna make a select for the "Role" with all the roles already present in the database.
But when I select a roles and I post my form, in the json the property take the value of the Object already existant in the database with the same role that I wanted to put on my new user, how can I just take the "text" instead of the whole object ?

```
<select ng-model="formData.role"
        ng-options="user as user.role for user in users">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-options="u.role as u.role for u in users"` will do the trick. Here is a demo:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.users = [{firstname: 'Jon', role : 'Admin'},
                  {firstname: 'Rob', role : 'User'},
                  {firstname: 'Ned', role : 'Guest'}];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Roles: <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="u.role as u.role for u in users"></select>
  selected: {{selected}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this

```
<select ng-model="formData.role"
     ng-options="user.role as user.role for user in users">
</select>
```

Also you can refer to [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-)

Comment: Thanks, I'm dumb haha

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want user.role then it should be text not whole user:

```
<select ng-model="formData.role"
        ng-options="user.role as user.role for user in users">
</select>
```